# What are the best practices for heartbeat signal

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Ibm Worklight provides [method sets the interval of the heartbeat signal](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_setheartbeatinterval.html) and I am using it but could anyone please tell me What is the best practices for heart beat interval and server session time out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the heartbeat is (quoting from the link above): ".... to ensure that the session with the server is kept alive when the app does not issue any call to the server (such as invokeProcedure)."
The heartbeat is not being sent if the application has moved to the background (or stopped) allowing the session to expire.
This is why you should sync the hearbeat time with the session expiration timeout parameter in the server.
See more in: [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_optimizing_and_tuning_of_ibm_wl_server.html?resultof=%22heartbeat%22%20)

(search for "heartbeat")